# Store letter counts of a file into an array

Tags: c

The question on my assignment is that I have to store counts of all letters in an array, lowercase and uppercase are treated the same. the strategy I used was to convert all the letters to uppercase and then count them. However, when I try to print the output, it's not giving me the correct output.

For example, I had a file that read:

> ADDadd

But for the output it gave me some crazy numbers for each letter.

Here's my code (a little messy):

```
void loadText(char story[])
{
    FILE *input;
    int letter = 0;
    int other = 0;
    int totalcharacter;
    char words;

    input = fopen(story, "r");

    while(fscanf(input, "%c", &words) != EOF)
    {
        if ((words >= 'A') && (words <= 'z'))
        {
            letter++;
        }
        else
        {
            other++;
        }
    }

    totalcharacter = letter + other;

    printf("Letters: %d\n", letter);
    printf("Characters: %d\n", totalcharacter);

    int typeofletter[26];               
    int i = 0;

    while(fscanf(input, "%c", &words) != EOF)
    {
        if ((words >= 'a') && (words <= 'z'))
        {
            words = toupper(words);
        }

        if((words >= 'A') && (words<='Z'))
        {
            typeofletter[words - 'A']++;
        }
    }

    for(i = 0; i < 26; i++)
    {
        if(typeofletter[i] != 0)
        {
            printf("%c occurs %d times \n", i + 'A', typeofletter[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Calling characters words is pretty damn confusing.

Comment: Try initializing `typeofletter` array to 0.

`int typeofletter[26] = {0}`

Comment: You don't check return of fopen so you have no idea if you actually opened the file. Secondly, where do you think fscanf carries on reading from in your second loop?

Comment: initializing didn't work D:
Asthor do you mind explaining a little more? thanks

Comment: If you fscanf through a file until you hit an EOF, what do you think happens next time you call EOF? You need to reset where you are reading in the file you wanna start from the start again.

Comment: thank you so much Asthor, i understand now. and initializing was also needed too, so thank you too GoldRoger.

Answer (score 1):

Try initializing `typeofletter` array to 0. `int typeofletter[26] = {0}` –  GoldRoger

Secondly, where do you think fscanf carries on reading from in your second loop?
If you fscanf through a file until you hit an EOF, what do you think happens next time you call EOF? You need to reset where you are reading in the file you wanna start from the start again. –  Asthor